# Oracle database and repository pattern in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have database created in oracle. I usually connect to database in my app using this code:

```
OracleConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
    sb.DataSource = "localhost";
    sb.UserID = "user";
    sb.Password = "password";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(sb.ToString());
    conn.Open();
```

I also use this code to do any statements:

```
OracleDataAdapter sd = new OracleDataAdapter("select, insert etc.", conn);
```

Let's say that I have 2 tables in my database, 1. People, 2. Places. And now I want to create repository for table - People.

So, what are steps to achieve it? , please correct me if I'm wrong.

I create a class which takes tables properties:

```
    public class People
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I create Interface:

```
    public interface IPeople
{
    void Insert(People person);
    void Update(People person);
    void Delete(People person);
    People GetById(People person);
    IEnumerable<People> SelectAll();
}
```

And I don't know what's next and how to use it. I'm confused, where do I do connection to my database?
I am sorry, maybe I ask stupid and simply questions, but I google repository patterns, and I still can't understand how to implement it and use it correctly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The underlying RDBMS doesn't make any difference in how you implement the Repository pattern. Instead of building it from scratch though, use an ORM like EF

Comment: Firstly, I'd say that `People` should probably be `Person`, `IPeople` should probably be `PersonRepository`, and you should definitely start following .NET naming conventions, e.g. `FirstName` rather than `first_name`. Beyond that, I'd say "How do I implement the repository pattern" is a very broad question for Stack Overflow. It sounds like you should probably create/open/use/close the connection in each of the methods you've mentioned... If indeed you need to implement it yourself rather than using an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this, but this way not so good. I try comment what you have to do. Use correctly name of your classes and propoerties, If you have problem with it you can use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) it is very helpful tool. Also as other wrote better idea will be use some ORM like `EntityFramework` or `NHibernate`.

```
 //change class name and property names , You need to use coding conventions 
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//this is a person repository interface
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    void Insert(People person);
    void Update(People person);
    void Delete(People person);
    People GetById(People person);
    IEnumerable<People> SelectAll();
}

//this class implement your interface
class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private OracleConnection conn;

    //add constructor which create connection to DB
    public PersonRepository()
    {
        OracleConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        sb.DataSource = "localhost";
        sb.UserID = "user";
        sb.Password = "password";
        conn = new OracleConnection(sb.ToString());
    }


    public void Delete(Person person)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Person GetById(Person person)
    {
        //Use try finally block to open and close connection
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            //example select by id
            OracleDataAdapter sd = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE PERSON.Id == " + person.Id,
                conn);
            return new Person();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Insert(Person person)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> SelectAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(Person person)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `using` instead of `try-finally`? Actually, disposing the connection at the end without creating it at the beginning of function looks like an anti-pattern

Comment: @grek40 Basically it give the same result ,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Yes, basically the 2 sentences of my comment are addressing separate concerns. 1st is about `using` and second is about the bad effect of `Dispose` on 2 consecutive calls to `GetById`, since reopening a disposed connection may be a problem.

Comment: I have an error in People GetById(People person)
not all code paths return a value.

Comment: @ktos1234 You need return collection Person.